# how to find no of elements in grid view in opium

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

I'm not able to click on element in a grid view. All elements are grid view in linear layout. I found the size of screen and I am able to scroll up down on screen. but I'm not able to click on a particular element. Here is a image of uiautomator. I am scrolling image using this code.

```
void swipe_vertical() throws InterruptedException{
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int height = size.height;
    int width = size.width;
    System.out.println("height=" +size.height+"width="+size.width);
    int startx = size.width/2;
    int endx = size.width/2;
    int starty = size.height - size.height/4;
    //int starty = size.height - size.height/6;
    //int starty = size.height - size.height/8;
    int endy = size.height/4;
    System.out.println("vertical swipe");
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    driver.swipe(startx,starty,endx,endy,200);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.swipe(endx,endy,startx,starty,200);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used Launcher as an example, which uses a RecyclerView inside a FrameLayout, but you can use it on your application and should work too.

```
/**
 * @@Test comment here@@
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void culebraGeneratedTest() throws Exception {
    (new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.launcher3:id/apps_list_view").packageName("com.android.launcher3"))).getChildByDescription(new UiSelector().description("TemperatureConverter"), "TemperatureConverter", true).click();
}
```

This test tried to find a child of `apps_list_view` with content description `TemperatureConverter`, scrolling if necessary, and then clicking on it.

If you are interested this test was automatically generated using [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com).